# django 2nd html page not visible

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

we expect another contact.html page to be visible here. that page defined in another specific html file.

[image: [![]enter image description here][3]][3]

[3]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/be9DD.png[![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/be9DD.png%5B!%5Benter) image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvnXo.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvnXo.png)I am resently develop an website as a beginer and got  the error like. **expected page is not loading instred of 404(page not found) error is showing.[image: error 1]**

Comment: please post your urls.py and related views.py

Comment: Please edit your answer and add your urls.py and views.py there.

Comment: the url is .../contact not ... /contact.html

Comment: still now  the error is not clear help me with this @Razenstein alredy add the views.py i will uplood the url.py also

Answer (score 0):

oupadate your urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('index',views.index,name='index'),
    path('contact', views.contact, name = "contact"),
    
    
]
```

and type 'contact' in browsers url